# Java create buttons dynamically in grid

Tags: java, button

I am making a desktop application in java where I want to create the buttons dynamically. The dynamically created button should be placed in a grid like structure. Now my concern is that, if I want to access those buttons, then how can i do that since I dont have the ID of the particular button ?

```
setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
        {
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
            jPanel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            jPanel1.add(new JButton(linesArray[i]), c);        

            jPanel1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0,0,1,0,Color.BLACK));

        }
```

How can i access the butons through a particular ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `array` which will hold all your buttons:

```
JButton[] buttons = new JButton[dataCount];
```

and then add buttons to it, and call the button by `array`:

```
buttons[i] = new JButton(linesArray[i]), c);
jPanel1.add(buttons[i]);
```